# How to Hide the Toolbar of XMind Application?

Tags: user-interface

How can I hide/show XMind's toolbar in order to have larger working space; notice that Full Screen mode is not helpful because it is NOT particularly designed for full functioning mindmaps.

Comment: Your claim is NOT convincing. From a Windows API programmer's point of view, it is seemingly enough to find the id of the toolbar window/control and then to send a Windows message with 'hide' message argument to that window. There may be a ready tiny tool or script to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Press Ctrl+Shift+L to open up the list of XMind customizable functions; from the list find "Toggle Toolbar Visibility" and double click it. Done.

Your can also assign a hotkey to toggle toolbar visibility from menu Edit -> Preferences -> Keys

> Thanks to @JSanchez and @ramhound for their contributions though
>   weren't the true answer.

Comment: In XMind 7 the quick access entry only appears if you map a key for the toggle action.

Answer (score 1):

While it can be hidden, you won't gain any more screen real estate, as the place holder for the toolbar remains. There are two classes you can hide: `[CLASS:ReBarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]` and `[CLASS:SWT_Window0; INSTANCE:2]`

`ReBarWindow32` resides within `SWT_Window0` so you can just hide the latter and the toolbar will disappear. The code below is a very simple (no error checking of any kind) AutoIt! script that does just that. [Download and install AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/)!, copy and paste the code, press F5 and if XMind is open, watch the toolbar appear and disappear as you run the script.

Someone smarter than me can probably make it work better. :-)

```
If WinExists("XMind") Then
    WinActivate("XMind")
    $hndWindow = WinGetHandle("XMind")
    ConsoleWrite("Handle: " & $hndWindow & @CRLF)
    $hndTBar = ControlGetHandle($hndWindow,"","[CLASS:SWT_Window0; INSTANCE:2]")
    ;[CLASS:SWT_Window0; INSTANCE:2] [CLASS:ReBarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]
    ConsoleWrite("TBar Handle: " & $hndTBar & @CRLF)
    if ControlCommand($hndTBar,"","","IsVisible") Then
        $retVal = ControlHide($hndTBar,"","")
    Else
        $retVal = ControlShow($hndTBar,"","")
    EndIf
    ConsoleWrite("retVal: " & $retVal & @CRLF)
EndIf
```